# Cómo obtengo una cadena específica en un string usando expresiones regulares de Python

Tags: python, regex

Tengo este string:
`color-purple, designer-allison_parris, formality-6, sizescale-us_combined, type-dress`
De lo cual necesito obtener sólo la palabra que se encuentre después de `color-`, o sea necesito obtener `purple`.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
.*?color-(\w+).*
```

Explicación:

- **`.*?`** ⇒ cualquier carácter excepto `\n` (0 o más veces (que coincida con la menor cantidad posible))
- **`color-`** ⇒ el texto `color-`
- **`(`** ⇒ *agrupar* y capturar en grupo 1:
- **`\w+`** ⇒ caracteres de palabra (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`) (1 o más veces (que coincida con la mayor cantidad posible))
- **`)`** ⇒ fin de grupo 1
- **`.*`** ⇒ cualquier carácter excepto `\n` (0 o más veces  (que coincida con la mayor cantidad posible))

Visualmente:

[image: visual]

El grupo 1 puede recuperar en Python como sigue:

- *Código:*

  ```python
  import re

  str = 'color-purple, designer-allison_parris, formality-6, sizescale-us_combined, type-dress'
  match = re.search(r'.*?color-(\w+).*', str)

  if match:
      print match.group(1)
  ```
- *Salida:*

  ```
  purple
  ```

Ver [*demo*](https://ideone.com/ncmk2c) en línea.

Comment: Perfecto, funciona. Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¡Qué bien! - ¡Oye, amigo! Tal vez olvidaste aceptar la respuesta. ;)

Answer (score 0):

saludos, asumiendo que siempre es color la primer palabra puedes usar simplemente un python string replace y remplazar phyton por nada, por ejemplo:

> cadena = "color-purple, designer-allison_parris, formality-6, sizescale-us_combined, type-dress"
> cadena2 = cadena.replace("color", "")

tambien podrias usar:

> cadena = "color-purple, designer-allison_parris, formality-6, sizescale-us_combined, type-dress"
> cadena2 = cadena[4:] #es decir de la cadena, recupera de la posicion 4 hasta el final

en caso de que la palabra cambie de lugar, entonces primero usar una busqueda:

> cadena = "color-purple, designer-allison_parris, formality-6, sizescale-us_combined, type-dress"
> poscicion_inicial = cadena.find("color") # esto regresaria la posicion donde inicia la palabra color
> posicion_inicial = posicion_inicial + 5 # se añaden 5 caracteres, ya que color tiene 5, en caso de querer incluir el - agregar uno mas
> cadena2 = cadena[posicion_inicial:] # recupera la cadena desde la posicion inicial calculada hasta el final.

tambien agrega esto para obtener solo el color que necesitas:

> cadena = "color-purple, designer-allison_parris, formality-6, sizescale-us_combined, type-dress"
>
> cadena_color = cadena.split(",")[0].trim # split divide la cadena usando la coma, en caos de no poner un valor especifico la corta usando los espacios, adicionalmente trim elimina espacios al inicio y al final de la cadena
>
> posicion_inicial = posicion_inicial + 5 # se añaden 5 caracteres, ya que color tiene 5, en caso de querer incluir el - agregar uno mas
>
> cadena2 = cadena_color[posicion_inicial:] # recupera la cadena desde la posicion inicial calculada hasta el final.

o

> cadena2 = cadena_color.replace("color-", "")

Comment: La pregunta iba sobre expresiones regulares, y no has usado ninguna en la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por sugerir una respuesta alternativa, pero era necesario usar expresiones regulares, de todas maneras se agradece.